# How to implement an input dialog in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm

I am using React Typescript and want to pop up a user input dialog, allowing the user to input a value before feeding that back to the function the button is currently executing.

This is such a simple use case, I can't believe I cannot find any modules or examples of how to do this anywhere. There are plenty of dialog npm modules for React JS, but none that work with Typescript that I can find.

Has someone done something similar and can advise how to do this in ReactTS?

Comment: Are you asking how to write your own component that does this, or for someone to recommend you a library?

Comment: Either. Happy to write my own if there are some pointers of where to start but even better if there's a library to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can just use https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal for your dialog. Remember to install even the types: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-modal